# Проверить дату и время в php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. у меня в базе данных, есть поля с датой и временем. например в таблице users
есть поле time_left и там в таком формате записана дата "c  10-2-2014   по  10-2-2014 
c  17:00  по  18:00". Нужно определить если эта дата уже прошла, то есть сравнивать с текущей. не знаю как это на пхп сделать. спасибо 
p.s. имеется в виду дата после "по"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить дату в таком формате это очень, очень и очень плохо. Из-за этого вы лишены возможности производить манипуляции с датой без лишних танцев с бубном. Правильнее было бы иметь 2 `DATETIME` столбца `from`, `to` и хранить там дату и время в таком формате: `2014-02-10 17:00:00` и `2014-02-10 18:00:00`

Настоятельно рекомендую переделать.

Почему у вас буквы "с" английские?

В вашем же случае придется использовать регулярные выражения, примерно так:

```
$date = "c 10-2-2014 по 10-2-2014 c 17:00 по 18:00";
preg_match('|c\s\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}\sпо\s(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})\sc\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\sпо\s(\d{1,2}:\d{2})|', $date, $match);

$realTime = strtotime($match[1] . ' ' . $match[2]);
if (time() > $realTime) {
    // прошла
}
```

Но это плохой способ

Comment: да, по правилам построения бд нужно делать два отдельных поля, но уже придется переделывать кучу всего, поэтому уже не буду.

Comment: Потратьте на это время. Сделайте всё же две дополнительные колонки с временем, а в этом поле значение пересчитываейте по тригеру on insert/delete

Comment: неужели действительно существуют в мире люди, которые проектируют такие таблицы? о чём они думают? "лень писать парсер 'с ... по ...  . Пока так пусть будет,а потом разберусь". Нет ничего более постоянного, чем временное.

Comment: я не знаком с триггерами, не пользовался ими. Просто у меня уже есть кучу ссылок на таблицу time_left, не только в пхп коде, но и на java. да, я знаю что это глупо. но это мое первое приложение. по-моему это первая нормальная форма, что атрибут должен быть неделимым.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, людей которые так проектируют БД тут полный сайт.