# Удалить произвольную дату из текста

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть некий текст, в котором может быть произвольная дата вида **dd.mm.yyyy**
и необходимо удалить из него эту дату регулярным выражением. С регулярками всегда сложности.. Подскажите, заранее Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверить дату и время в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/323129/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2-php)

Answer (score 1):

Дополню Manitikyl. Если дата будет через тире или точку.

```
$VAR_DATA = 'this data 31-05-2018';
echo preg_replace("/([0-2]\d|3[01])(\.|\-)(0\d|1[012])(\.|\-)(\d{2,4})/", "", $VAR_DATA);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$VAR_DATA = 'this data 31.05.2018';
echo preg_replace("/([0-2]\d|3[01])\.(0\d|1[012])\.(\d{2,4})/", "", $VAR_DATA);
```